# Unable to start php-fpm - "cannot get uid for user 'apache'"

Tags: linux, nginx, php

On a fresh AWS Linux HVM box, I ran the commands:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install git nginx php-fpm
```

I then tried to `sudo service start php-fpm`, but got the error:

```
Starting php-fpm: [10-Sep-2014 20:52:39] ERROR: [pool www] cannot get uid for user 'apache'
[10-Sep-2014 20:52:39] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Where am I going wrong and where is the apache user coming from?

Comment: You can go to `/etc/passwd` and see if user `apache` is inside this file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `apache` user comes from `php-fpm.conf` file. It does not matter that you run it as root, the service will start as the user which is configured in this file.

Find your `php-fpm.conf` file. It should be somwhere in `/etc`. Edit it and change lines

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

to

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

I'm assuming your default nginx configuration also uses the `www-data` user.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Example of real location (You may have PHP 7.0, 7.1, 7.2) you path may be a tad different: `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf` -- In newer versions this is located in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and you'll find `user/group` around line `23`

Comment: For me on 7.0 this was in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, under `listen.group` and `listen.owner`.

Answer (score 1):

For a docker OpenShift no root way, prepare groups in build

```
vim /etc/groups
```

e.g. `nobody:x:999:`

it's after some update in **php-fpm**

Answer (score 1):

Just adding for the latest ubuntu 18.04,  it was a different user(magento) and was running on PHP 7.2.

```
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager...
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud php-fpm7.2[8328]: [12-Feb-2020 14:33:23] ERROR: [pool magento] cannot get uid for user 'magento'
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud php-fpm7.2[8328]: [12-Feb-2020 14:33:23] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 14:33:23 same-cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

From terminal,

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/magento.conf
```

I changed the contents as follows in the `magento.conf` file:

```
[magento]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-magento.sock
```

In order to give effect, run the following commands:

```
sudo systectl restart apache2
```

To see the status

```
systemctl status php7.2-fpm.service
```

Additional commands to enable fpm

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```